# firebaseのhostingが更新されない

Tags: firebase

firebaseを使用しています。
バグ修正のため、本日すでに10回以上のdeployをしています。
すると、ある時からhostingが更新されなくなりました。
deployのしすぎの影響でしょうか。
詳しい方教えていただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

サーバーキャッシュが効いてるからじゃないでしょうか？
firebase.jsonのheadersで該当のソースをキャッシュしない設定にすれば直りませんか？